# Wordpress receiving a payload via a response url from third party API

Tags: php, wordpress, api

I am sending & receiving JSON responses from a third party API, in one instance though they need to send a response to a url on my site ie: https://my-wordpress-site/api/confirm?transaction=T0efewgfweg78105 Can someone point me in the right direction on how to receive the payload from this response? The payload will be a JSON response like: “Status”: "Success" What script will I run on https://my-wordpress-site/api/confirm.php

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the situation correctly
You can fetch this data with this snippet:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['transaction']) && !empty($_REQUEST['transaction']))
{

$response_body = file_get_contents('php://input'); 
$data = json_decode($response_body);

}
```

php://input is a read-only stream that allows you to read raw data from the request body